# run nodejs script in xcode run script

Tags: xcode, node.js

I've created a run script in xcode for my iphone app which gets executed whenever i build the app.

In this script i want to run a node.js script after a few shell commands. 
Unfortunately i get receive the following error.

```
/Users/foo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-atqonvdooptyhieprtduibmymygy/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Script-F4F199C717B9477900AA658B.sh: 
line 12: node: command not found
```

this is basically the script:

```
SRC_DIR="/path"
node "$SRC_DIR/deployment/deploy.js"
```

when i execute the same script in the terminal it works just fine.

has anyone an idea to get node scripts to run in xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `node /path/` i had to use the path to the node binary e.g. `/usr/local/bin/node "$SRC_DIR/deployment/deploy.js"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to run node from the same folder as the script is actually running?. You could be having a permission issue.

Comment: i had some permission issues with the scripts as well, thx for that! The fix for me was to just use the binary path for node.